# How to simplify my Active Record code (I want to filter has_many using join table column)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is my schema

```
  create_table "duties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "is_general", default: false
    t.boolean "write_all", default: true
  end

  create_table "duties_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "duty_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.boolean "has_write_access", default: true
    t.index ["duty_id"], name: "index_duties_users_on_duty_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_duties_users_on_user_id"
   end
    
   create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string "mail"
     t.text "password_digest"
     t.datetime "birth_date"
     t.boolean "is_admin", default: false
     t.integer "rating", default: 0
     t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
     t.string "name", default: ""
     t.string "surname", default: ""
     t.string "patronymic", default: ""
     t.datetime "restore_date", default: "2021-02-11 09:57:14"
     t.boolean "is_boss", default: false
   end
```

My join model

```
class DutyUser < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "duties_users"
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :duty
end
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord     
    has_secure_password   
    has_many :duties_users, class_name: "DutyUser"
    has_many :duties, through: :duties_users, class_name: "Duty"
end
```

And duty model

```
class Duty < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :duties_users, class_name: "DutyUser"
  has_many :users, through: :duties_users, class_name: "User"

end
```

I want to find all users who have write acces to a specific duty. In order to achive it i need to use something like this:

```
 Duty.first.duties_users.find_all{|m| m.has_write_access}.map{|m| m.user}
```

How can i simplify this line of code?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 0):

The key points here are:

- Duty *has_many* users. So if you have a `duty`, you can always do `duty.users` and that will give you the users in what's known as an "ActiveRecord Relation"
- ActiveRecord Relations act a lot like arrays, except that they only give you access to instances of one model (in this case, duty.users will return a relation full of User instances) which allow you to run further queries, as well as any class methods on User. Note that unlike an array, a Relation doesn't actually contain anything. It quietly builds some SQL, and only sends that SQL to the database when you force it to (e.g. by iterating over it with `.each`, or asking for a `.count`)
- Queries can be done using the `where` method - e.g. `.where(has_write_access: true)` - this is done in the database, so it's super quick.